# How do I dynamically choose an excel sheet to reference in a formula?

Tags: excel

I have an xlsx with sheets named "A", "B", "C", etc.  I need to form a table with the names "A", "B", "C" as the first column, and some data from the same cell in each sheet as the second column.  So for example, this might look like:

```
   Sheet          Data
   A              =A!C2
   B              =B!C2
```

In my "Data" column, is there some way to reference the names "A" and "B" from the "Sheet" column, so I can just fill the forumla in once and have it update as I add more sheets?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your sheet name `A` is in `A2` - use this in B2: `=INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!C2")`

Comment: @user200814 If you're happy with the solution proposed - please accept the answer by ticking it, this will mark the question solved.